# iterator, do something when hasNext() equals false

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have a while loop that iterates through an `ArrayList` but I want to do something when the iteration reaches the last string in this list of strings.

How could this be done?

```
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            //do stuff here
            }

            do something to list string in list?
```

Comment: So you want to find the _last_ element in an iteration? why not just do `if(!i.hasNext()){` ?

Comment: Are you wanting to do something after the last element, or with the last element?

Comment: yes and do something to that string when I find it having iterated through all strings before it in the array

Comment: `list.get(list.size() - 1)` will return the last element of the list. Use it after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Have a local variable in the outer scope to remember the last item:

```
String last = null;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  last = iterator.next();
}

... now last refers to the last item.
```

If you want to know you're on the last item while still within the loop, then simply check that with `hasNext()` after having called `next()` to retrieve the current iteration's item.

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  String s = iterator.next();
  if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
     // here s is guaranteed to refer to the last item
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = null;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  str = iterator.next();//str will contain the string
}
System.out.print(str);
```

or

```
arrayList.get(arrayList.size()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
string lastItem = list.get(list.size() - 1);
```

### update

as per your comment you need to user `iterator.hasNext()` so you can try(which is not recommended):

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) 
{
   if(!iterator.hasNext())
   {
     //do stuff here
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to say iterator.hasNext() == false (meaning there is no next element so you must be on the last one)?

Comment: You just did. But using `!iterator.hasNext()` would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it that way if you would like to do it inside the loop and to prevent a NullPointerException when the list is empty:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String item = iterator.next();
    //do something here
    if(!iterator.hasNext()) {
        //do stuff with last item here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("One");
        list.add("Two");
        list.add("Three");
        list.add("Fore");
        list.add("Last");

        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            String item = iterator.next();
            i++;
            if(!iterator.hasNext()) {
                // do what you want with the last one
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        }
```

Hope that helps, Salam

Comment: `iterator.hasNext()` is precisely such method for which you claim that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you ^^ I modify my code now, I think this is much better.. Thank you again :) Salam